# how to prepare time to event value in case of longitudinal data for Survival Analysis

Tags: survival, panel-data, cox-model, time-varying-covariate, proportional-hazards

I have longitudinal transaction data of a retail store where each row is a transaction done by an individual. I would like to perform a survival analysis to analyse how long a customer will transact before churning. Here I am defining **churn** as someone who has not made any transaction in **last 3 months from current time**. I  am planning to use Cox Proportional Hazard Model, it requires **tenure** or **time_to_event** parameter. What is the correct way to represent **tenure** in this case of churn for below data

Below is the sample of data

```
Id.    Visit_date.       Amount.   Tenure     Churn     Age     Income
1.     04/03/2020        500        ?           No      40      56K
1.     05/03/2020        300        ?           No      32      60K
1.     05/23/2020        800        ?           No      28      90K
1.     07/04/2020        700        ?           No      40      56K
2.     02/03/2020        500        ?          Yes      43      50K
2.     01/12/2020        300        ?          Yes      60      90K
3.     03/23/2020        800        ?           No      18      80K
4.     07/04/2020        700        ?           No      20      40K
```

What is the correct way to put Time_to_event or Tenure value for CoxPH model?

Comment: Seeme to be recurrent events, which has its own tag [tag:recurrent-events].  Consider adding that tag (then you need to drop one other, as five is max number of tags.)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you for the response. I am new to survival analysis and I didn't understand what you said, can you please elaborate on your answer.